# CSS - Simple text texture

Tags: html, css

I need to have `h1`s textured the same way as this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCGE5.png

But I can't find how it is done.

I took the screenshot from this website: http://www.eminem.com/home

I have this code for h1:

```
h1{
    margin-top:20px;
     border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 1px;
border-color: #333333;
font-weight:normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: 'Steelfish Rg', 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: Use `background-clip`? http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

Comment: @Terry it doesn't work in IE while in the link it does

Comment: Well maybe it helps to **mention what browsers do you want to support**.

Comment: Did you even try to inspect the element of interest? The site is clearly using an image as a placeholder, not text: the logo is an image file http://www.eminem.com/sites/deveminem.umg.edrupalgardens.com/files/201310/logo_eminem.png. If you want a textured title that accommodates dynamic text, `background-clip` is likely the only way.

Comment: @Terry I want it to work in at least IE, Chrome, Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've inspected the source of the page of interest you can see that the logo is hardcoded in the form of an [image file](http://www.eminem.com/sites/deveminem.umg.edrupalgardens.com/files/201310/logo_eminem.png).

For dynamically-textured text, you can use the `background-clip` property, which is supported in WebKit browsers so far. There are other fallbacks available, and the techniques are well-documented here: http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/

```css
h1{
  /* Background clip */
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/RwVIbSX.jpg); /* Change URL to texture file name */
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  
  /* Other styles */
  margin-top:20px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-color: #333333;
  font-weight:normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Steelfish Rg', 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

```html
<h1>Title Text</h1>
```

Comment: That website does something else, background-clip does not work in IE while what the linked website does, works.

Comment: After doing some research and finding a fallback code it works 'ok'

Answer (score 0):

For text effects like these, you are better off using an image, rather than code it. The reason being compatibility. Although the `background clip` is something worth exploring, it is only webkit compliant. A more practical solution is an image for the same reason.